# Determine whether a polynomial is reducible over a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

I'm trying to determine whether a $\mathbb F_5[x] / (x^2 + x + 2)$ is a field. This is equivalent to determining whether $x^2 + x + 2$ is reducible over $\mathbb F_5[x]$.

I can prove reducibility by showing that there are two nonzero $a(x), b(x) \in \mathbb F_5[x]$ such that $a(x)b(x) = x^2 + x + 2$. There are 25 elements in $F_5[x]$ of degree ≤ 1, representable as $Ax + B$ for $0 \leq A, B < 5$. I have tried several such $a(x), b(x)$'s of this form and can't find a pair that satisfies this equation, so I'm inclined to believe $x^2 + x + 2$ is irreducible.

Is there a way to prove that this is true without exhaustively multiplying all pairs of 25 elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $x^2+x+2$ were reducible in $\mathbb F_5$, it would have to factor into linear polynomials $x-a$ and $x-b$ where $a,b\in\mathbb F_5$. Therefore, it would have to have a root in $\mathbb F_5$. But no $x\in\mathbb F_5$ gives a value of zero for the polynomial, so it is irreducible.

Comment: why is it not possible that $x^2 + x + 2$ factors into non-monic polynomials? couldn't there be a factorisation of the form $(2x+m)(3x+n) = x^2 + x +2$?

Comment: @DG Then you would have (say) $2x+m=0$, and since 5 is a prime number division by 2 is well-defined in the field, so you would still get a root $r$. Then you would be able to rewrite the factorisation as $(x-r)(x-s)$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $deg(x^2+x+2)=2$,$x^2+x+2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F_5}$ iff it has no roots in $\mathbb{F_5}$.But all the possible roots are $\{[0]_5,[1]_5,[2]_5,[3]_5,[4]_5\}$ so...

Comment: what is $[k]_5$?

Comment: Isn't it $\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{5\mathbb{Z}}=\mathbb{F_5}$?,$[k]_5=\{x\in\mathbb{Z}:x\equiv k(mod5)\}$

Answer (score 1):

Another helpful way to see this is to consider the discriminate of a quadratic, at least when the characteristic of your field is not 2. According to the quadratic equation, it has a factor iff `D = b^2 - 4ac` is a square. Here, D is 2, and the squares in your field are 0,1,4,9=4,16=1. Thus, 2 is not a square so it has no roots.

This also shows the extension field is obtained by adding a square root of 2 and there is only one other quadratic extension obtained by adding a square root of 3.

Comment: I get $D=-7=-2$, also not a square.

Comment: There is only one quadratic extension of $\mathbb F_5$, namely $\mathbb F_{25}$.

Comment: You're right.... Not enough coffee before I answered.  I'll update it